# PreDestroy exception while deploying app to glassfish 4.1.2

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-4, glassfish-4.1, glassfish-5

## PreDestroy exception while deploying app

### Environment Details

- GlassFish 4.1.2 full platform:
- JDK version: 1.8.0_171
- OS: macOS 10.13.4
- Database: H2 in memory

---

### Problem Description

Deploying war file to glassfish results in the exception

> The lifecycle method [close] must not throw a checked exception

I expect the war file to be deployed successfully like it is on other JEE containers

## Easily reproducible

```
Exception while deploying the app [sec-access-issue-0.1] : The lifecycle method [close] must not throw a checked exception. Related annotation information: annotation [@javax.annotation.PreDestroy()] on annotated element [public void org.grails.async.factory.future.CachedThreadPoolPromiseFactory.close() throws java.io.IOException] of type [METHOD]
The lifecycle method [close] must not throw a checked exception. Related annotation information: annotation [@javax.annotation.PreDestroy()] on annotated element [public void org.grails.async.factory.future.CachedThreadPoolPromiseFactory.close() throws java.io.IOException] of type [METHOD]
    at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:373)
    at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:381)
    at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:217)
    at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:134)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.processAnnotations(Archivist.java:627)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:463)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:447)
    at org.glassfish.web.deployment.archivist.WebArchivist.postAnnotationProcess(WebArchivist.java:338)
    at org.glassfish.web.deployment.archivist.WebArchivist.postAnnotationProcess(WebArchivist.java:91)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readRestDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:421)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:396)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:271)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:280)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:241)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openArchive(ApplicationFactory.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.processDOL(DolProvider.java:203)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:227)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:881)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:821)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:377)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:253)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:231)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:275)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:133)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:309)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1139)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:375)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter$2.service(RestAdapter.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The lifecycle method [close] must not throw a checked exception
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.annotation.handlers.AbstractResourceHandler.validateAnnotatedLifecycleMethod(AbstractResourceHandler.java:186)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.annotation.handlers.PreDestroyHandler.processAnnotation(PreDestroyHandler.java:69)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.annotation.handlers.AbstractResourceHandler.processAnnotation(AbstractResourceHandler.java:142)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.annotation.factory.SJSASFactory$LazyAnnotationHandler.processAnnotation(SJSASFactory.java:148)
    at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:350)
    ... 84 more
]]
```

### Steps to reproduce

Deploy the linked war file to glassfish
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m4_tDOQlzk_7fBh3EMV0vQ1Gx8mztiLn/view?usp=sharing

### Impact of Issue

I can't deploy an app to glassfish

Comment: Are you sure it worked on other server? PreDestroy must not throw checked exception is JavaEE Spec.

Comment: The generated war file deploys without issue on Tomcat.  

It's Glassfish where it fails. :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is  already described by the error message.

The PreDestroy method in the class org.grails.async.factory.future.CachedThreadPoolPromiseFactory MUST NOT throw a checked exception. Obviously it is doing this at the moment.

**Besides from that it looks like what you are trying to do doesn't make sense.**

Your WAR file contains SpringBoot JARs, if you want to build a SpringBoot application then you CAN NOT deploy it (at least not easily) on full Java EE servers (and it doesn't make sense!). SpringBoot applications are supposed to run on embedded servlet containers like Tomcat or Jetty.

Answer (score -2):

you need to handle checked exception on your end, add throws or try/catch block and handle java.io.IOException in your method.